# How to Segue using Custom UITableViewCell? Problems with passing data to the detail view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have created a custom UITableViewCell using the nib file. Then when I select the my custom UITableViewCell, I want to perform a segue and pass the data to the detail view controller. I have already set the segue identifier in the storyboard, and I put the `prepareForSegueWithIdentifier` in the  `- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` However, when I perform the segue, only the first row of the table view can be shown on the detailed page.

I have three questions:

**1. How to set the segue identifier for the custom UITableViewCell?**

Since I create the custom UITableViewCell in the xib file, it is difficult to connect the xib file with the main storyboards with other view controllers.

**2. If I change the class name of the table view cell in the storyboard, will it be my custom UITableViewCell?**

Specifically, in order to replace the default UItableViewCell in the storyboard to my custom UITableViewCell, I change the name of the class of the default UITableViewCell in the storyboard, to the name of my custom UITableViewCell. Then I Control + Drag to create a push segue and set the segue identifier. But it seems this one doesn't work either.

**3. Why every time I perform segue, the destination view controller only show the specific content of the first row of my table view?**

That is, whenever I select the first cell, the second cell, the third cell......, all I get after segue to the destination view controller is the content of the first cell. I am wondering whether the sender is my custom UITableViewCell? Or is the indexPath is nil? I am not sure.

My code is as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    customTableViewCell *cell;
    cell = (customTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    if (!cell) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"customTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSDictionary *photo = self.recentPhotos [indexPath.row];


    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("fetch photos", 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSURL *imageURL = [FlickrFetcher URLforPhoto:photo format:FlickrPhotoFormatSquare];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            NSString *title = [photo valueForKeyPath:FLICKR_PHOTO_TITLE];

            cell.cellLabel.text = title;



            UIImageView *cellImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
            [cellImageView setFrame: CGRectMake(10, 5, 45, 45)];
            [cellImageView.layer setCornerRadius:cellImageView.frame.size.width/2];
            cellImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

            [cell addSubview:cellImageView];

        });
    });

      return cell;
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"go" sender:indexPath];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
        NSDictionary *photo = self.recentPhotos [indexPath.row];
        NSURL *imageURL = [FlickrFetcher URLforPhoto:photo format:FlickrPhotoFormatLarge];
        NSString *title = [photo valueForKeyPath:FLICKR_PHOTO_TITLE];

        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"go"]) {
            if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[ViewImageViewController class]]) {
                ViewImageViewController *vivc = (ViewImageViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
                vivc.imageURL = imageURL;
                vivc.title = title;
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try debugging the method and looking at the value of sender? You provided the `indexPath` in the call to `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` but the you use the sender as a cell in `indexPathForCell:`.

I already see problems in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method as well. While scrolling the cells get reused, so when you perform a async call the block can and will be executed on the wrong cell. To prevent that call the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` again inside the dispatch_async callback.

Also you are adding a subview directly to the cell instead of using the `contentView` property.

Regarding your questions, as far as I know you cannot connect a segue from a nib file. To make it work properly you need to connect the segue from the prototype cell in the storyboard. You created a manual  segue and you're calling it when the user touches the cell. I think that it'll be easier for you to understand what's happening if you don't use segues at all and just call `showViewController:sender:` yourself.

Comment: Thanks so much! I try to debug the value of the sender. Whenever I select the cell, the console will display like this "2014-10-24 16:32:53.161 Flickr Photo App[1484:70177] <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000018016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}
2014-10-24 16:32:56.744 Flickr Photo App[1484:70177] <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000008016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}". Besides, I try to debug the value of indexPath, it is always "0"

Comment: The sender is the IndexPath. You are sending it on the call to the segue. Print the row property on it and you should see the correct value